# async pipe not subscribing to Observable Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router, angular2-observables, async-pipe

In Angular (v12) I've got a following component (using dummy variable names):

```
export class DataDetailsComponent {
    data$: Observable<MyDataModel>;

    constructor(dataService: DataService, route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
        this.data$ =
            combineLatest([dataService.getDataObservable(), router.events])
                .pipe(
                    filter(([,event]) => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
                    tap(([data, event]) => console.log((<ActivationEnd>event).snapshot.queryParams['id'])),
                    map(([data, event]) => data.filter(c => c.id === (<ActivationEnd>event).snapshot.queryParams['id'])[0]),
                    tap(dataItem => console.log(dataItem))
                );
        this.data$.subscribe(); // console.logs don't work without this
    }
}
```

And its template:

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else loading">
    <img [src]="data.url" [alt]="data.name">
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```

Data is not being rendered, and the browser console is empty if I don't actually subscribe to the `data$`. On the other hand, when I do place `this.data$.subscribe();`, console gets correct output, but the view is still empty (hangs on *Loading...*).

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Maybe your observable is returning falsy values, making *ngIf evaluate to false?

Comment: try `combineLatest([dataService.getDataObservable(), router.events]).subscribe(console.log))` to get more info

Comment: @AllanJuan but when I manually subscribe, I get very truthy values from `tap(console.log(...))`...

Comment: Probably a long shot but it is worth trying moving the setup code to ngOnInit to be sure it's not related to some uninitialised component state.  And what happens if you replace the real observable with a dummy of(true)?

Comment: Another thought.  First, note that the subscribe in the constructor and the subscribe in the ngFor will be happening at different times and therefore with potentially different values returned from the combineLatest.   Try another tap before the filter - when the ngFor subscribes if the combineLatest is not emitting, or it is filtered out, then you  would see what you are seeing.  You can also try a "startWith" to test the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was the router event that was not letting observable complete.
Apparently, it works if I move navigation from template to .ts and subscribe to `ActivatedRoute.params` instead of `Router.events`.

So, the parent component gets:

```
navigateToDetails(id: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/myRoute', id]);
}
```

instead of using `routerLink` in template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/myRoute']" [queryParams]="{id: item.id}">
```

And then, on `DataDetailsComponent` i can do:

```
constructor(dataService: DataService, route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.data$ =
            combineLatest([dataService.getDataObservable(), route.params])
                .pipe(map(([data, params]) => data.filter(c => c.id === params['id'])[0]));
    }
```

Reasons why are beyond me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

can be related to your combineLatest. check to see both observables are emitting data.

CombineLatest definition :

> Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each
> observable emits at least one value. This is the same behavior as
> withLatestFrom and can be a gotcha as there will be no output and no
> error but one (or more) of your inner observables is likely not
> functioning as intended, or a subscription is late.

you can use startWith operator to set some initial value for observables.

Comment: I am 100% sure that data is present. This is a details component accessed from data list, so the data is already loaded on the service. Furthermore, service holds data in `BehaviorSubject<T>`, so I'm forced to use initial value in constructor.